How can I select one of two columns from different tables as a single column
I have two tables.
tblAddress



PrimaryKey
AddressType
Address




1234
LOC
123 ST.


1234
MAL
456 TER



tblAccountInfo



PrimaryKey
Address




1234
123 ST.


5678
XYZ AVE



What I want is that if an account has a mailing address (MAL) in tblAddress to select that
address and if it does not to select the account address.
I tried to use an or statement based on the addresstype column and the accountinfo address column but it seems to always select the account info address even if the other is available.

Your output does not agree with the verbal description in your question.

Please show your current query that is not working and also include the expected result. You probably need to use case expression to do what you want

FYI, SQL Server 2008 ran entirely out of support, and reached end of life, around 5 years ago. You really need to get that finalised upgrade plan from 6+ years ago implemented; using such an old version is only a security risk, and upgrading the instance to a (fully) supported version is only going to get harder and harder the longer you delay.

Does this answer your question? Get top 1 row of each group

You need to join those tables on PrimaryKey and use CASE WHEN syntax in your fields list. Something like this:
SELECT CASE WHEN a.AddressType = 'MAL' THEN i.Address ELSE a.Address END as final_address
FROM tblAddress a
LEFT JOIN tblAccountInfo i on a.PrimaryKey = i.PrimaryKey


This just shows 2 times 123 ST.

If I understand you correct you want to select from tblAccountInfo but show address from tblAddress if the type MAL exists.
You can use an outer apply for this.
select ai.PrimaryKey,
       isnull(a.Address, ai.Address) as Address
from   tblAccountInfo ai
  outer apply ( select top 1
                       a.Address
                from   tblAddress a
                where  a.PrimaryKey = ai.PrimaryKey
                and    a.AddressType = 'MAL'
              ) a

See this query at work here
the result is



PrimaryKey
Address




1234
456 TER


5678
XYZ AVE



If this is not what you are after, then please edit your question and explain in more detail, best also show the expected outcome.
EDIT
Since you are using an outdated version of SQL Server which has no outer apply, here is a version using left join
See left join version at work here
select ai.PrimaryKey,
       isnull(a.Address, ai.Address) as Address
from   tblAccountInfo ai
  left join ( select  a.PrimaryKey,
                      a.Address
                from  tblAddress a
                where a.AddressType = 'MAL'
              ) a
     on a.PrimaryKey = ai.PrimaryKey


I don't recall  Outer apply available in sql-server 2008?

@P.Salmon Oops, I read over that one, I updated my answer to also include a version that uses left join instead of outer apply

It is supported but you need to be on a high enough compatibility level.

You can leverage the COALESCE() function, which will return the first non-NULL value from a series of columns:
DECLARE @Addresses TABLE (PrimaryKey INT, AddressType NVARCHAR(8), Address NVARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO @Addresses (PrimaryKey, AddressType, Address) VALUES (1234, 'LOC', '123 ST.')
INSERT INTO @Addresses (PrimaryKey, AddressType, Address) VALUES (1234, 'MAL', '456 TER')

DECLARE @Accounts TABLE (PrimaryKey INT, Address NVARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO @Accounts (PrimaryKey, Address) VALUES (1234, '123 ST.')
INSERT INTO @Accounts (PrimaryKey, Address) VALUES (5678, 'XYZ AVE')
INSERT INTO @Accounts (PrimaryKey, Address) VALUES (8765, '5 ELM ST.')
INSERT INTO @Accounts (PrimaryKey, Address) VALUES (9999, NULL)

SELECT
    acct.PrimaryKey,
    COALESCE(addr.Address, acct.Address, 'No address found.') AS Address
FROM
    @Accounts acct
    LEFT JOIN @Addresses addr ON acct.PrimaryKey = addr.PrimaryKey
        AND addr.AddressType = 'MAL'

Note that this query is filtering table @Addresses right in the LEFT JOIN for only rows where AddressType equals 'MAL'.
Results:



PrimaryKey
Address




1234
456 TER


5678
XYZ AVE


8765
5 ELM ST.


9999
No address found.



